# SQL Procedures: posso usar uma tabela como parametro de um procedimento?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Sou iniciante em procedimentos.

Estou tentando inserir dados uma tabela usando um procedimento, em que recebo o nome da tabela, os nomes das colunas e os valores destas.

Como fazer para receber os tipos de dados que desejo, como uma tabela ou uma coluna?

Estou pensando  certo em usar um procedimento para isso?

Aqui vai um trecho do codigo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `inserirUsuario`(tableName varchar(45),column5 varchar 
(45),dado5 varchar(45),column6 varchar (45),dado6 varchar(45),column1 
varchar (45),dado1 varchar(45),column2 varchar (45),dado2 varchar(45), 
column3 varchar (45),dado3 varchar(45),column4 varchar (45),dado4 
varchar(45) )
BEGIN
DECLARE id int;
insert into endereco(column1, column2, column3, column4) values 
(dado1,dado2,dado3,dado4);
```

Comment: SQLServer, mySQL ?

Comment: A informação vem de onde? De uma aplicação? Do próprio SQL? Se o objetivo for só inserir dados numa tabela, não vejo o porquê de utilizar uma `Stored Procedure`.

Answer (score 0):

Você até pode montar uma procedure genérica que consiga inserir dados em qualquer tabela, mas isso não é algo comum a ser feito.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [InserirUsuario]
( @tableName varchar(45)
, @column1   varchar(45)
, @dado1     varchar(45)
, @column2   varchar(45)
, @dado2     varchar(45)
) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SET @SqlCommand = N'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '(' + @column1 + ',' + @column2 + 
') VALUES (''' + @dado1 + ''',''' + @dado2 + ''')'

  EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SqlCommand
END
```

Neste caso você montaria uma string com o seu comando e depois executaria ele, é claro que faltaria a questão de formato do campo, mas como citei, não é algo corriqueiro criar uma procedure genérica dessa forma, principalmente pois cada tabela pode ter uma quantidade diferente de campos.

Você poderia substituir o fato de criar vários campos de parâmetros para utilizar apenas um campo XML que poderia ter N campos de coluna e valor.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei um artigo em que é disponibilizado um script que permite a criação genérica de uma tabela.

O script seria

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Table_Structure (@InputSQL AS NVARCHAR(4000), @TableName AS NVARCHAR(128) = NULL) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @is_nullable BIT 
DECLARE @system_type_name NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @collation_name NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @NewLine NVARCHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- CRLF

DECLARE CUR_Table CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT  name ,
            is_nullable ,
            system_type_name ,
            collation_name
    FROM    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@InputSQL, NULL, NULL)
    WHERE   is_hidden = 0
    ORDER BY column_ordinal ASC 

OPEN CUR_Table

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_Table INTO @name, @is_nullable, @system_type_name,
    @collation_name

SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE [' + ISNULL(@TableName, 'TableName') + '] ('
    + @NewLine

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL += @NewLine + '[' + @name + ']' + ' ' + @system_type_name
            + CASE WHEN @collation_name IS NOT NULL
                   THEN '  COLLATE ' + @collation_name + ' '
                   ELSE ''
              END + CASE WHEN @is_nullable = 0 THEN ' NOT NULL '
                         ELSE ''
                    END + ',' 
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_Table INTO @name, @is_nullable, @system_type_name,
            @collation_name
    END

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 1) + @NewLine + ')'

CLOSE CUR_Table
DEALLOCATE CUR_Table

RETURN @SQL
end
```

Acredito que ele execute o que você deseja. Abaixo o link para o artigo na integra.

[Link do Artigo](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5699/auto-generate-create-table-script-based-on-sql-server-query/)